# windows service app capture DTMF from call made from Twilio

Tags: windows, service, twilio

we have developing a Windows app that needs to run in background (service) and periodically check a database that contain entries describing calls that need to be made at given times. we also need the user to enter a DTMF tone. Now all the twilio examples are web based so wondering if this is possible

Comment: Twilio has many different ways of sending DTMF, so if you could clarify the call flow, I can point you to the best approach. Not clear by your comment, "Now all the twilio examples are web based so wondering if this is possible". Do you have an example of the examples you reference?

Comment: start process (windows service or demon) ... every minute .. look for entrys in database describing phone calls that ned to be made... place call ..user presses 1  key ....all ok ... end call ...else end call and try again.... continue placing calls till no more in Q  .. back to slleep

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Twilio REST API Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) to place the outbound call and a [Gather Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather), with a nested [Say Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) (Text to Speech) to collect the DTMF entry. You can do similar using [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/make-outgoing-call) (drag drop widgets with GUI).

[Studio Usage Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide)

Comment: this is NOT a web api application . the server app is placing calls while in an endless timer based loop. all Twilio examples show sending the DTMF response to a response URL which is great if the app is web based. if u know a way to put a web app into continuous running mode I would love to know . Thank